# Can i run an MS visual studio dot.net project with just a console?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, console

I'm a newbie with the dot.net dev envirement and i had to run an app backend using the MS visual studio.
As i'm also running other servers in the same time i'm almost running out of memory in my pc.
I'd like to know if there is a way to run the MS visual studio project in a console without the need to run the whole editor.
Is that possible ?

[image]

Comment: You could use [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) to build the project, then run the compiled code as you would any other application.

Comment: Hi, if you just want to build and run the project and just like Timothy said, we can use the MSBuild or .NET CLI (if your project target to .NET Core type)：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/, if you still need to modify the code under this project, it seems unable and the VS editor is required.

Comment: Thanks for both. THe MS visual studio should be building the project and it generates probably an .exe somewhere ? i never need to edit the backend project code. Do you have a clue where that .exe is stored to just run it with the CLI ?

Comment: What's your project type? Usually, after you build this project and the .exe file is created under your project sub folder, you can search the .exe under your project store folder to find it. Do you want run this .exe on the local computer without opening VS IDE or move to other computer to run it?

Comment: Yes i want run it in the same computer. I have no clue which type, just i know it's a C# project. I will look in the IDE config maybe i'll find where .exe files are stored.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay response, please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019 and the .exe be created under 'Output path' folder, you can right click the project name under Solution Explorer window inside the IDE, choose 'Open Folder in File Explorer' to open the current project in File Explorer.